# Collections.sort generic method signature

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

Inside java.util.Collections we have the below method signature

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

I don't understand why one would specify

```
Comparator<? super T>
```

instead of

```
Comparator<T>
```

Which use cases does it cover?

Comment: Generics `PECS` rule

Comment: Why wouldn't it be specified that way?  If `S` is a supertype of `T`, then a `Comparator<S>` does just fine for comparing `T` objects - and this signature reflects that.

Comment: Are you aware that `List<Subclass>` is not a subtype of `List<Superclass>`, such that `sort(subclassList, superclassComparator)` would not type-check if the method signature required the `List` and the `Comparator` to have the same type argument? (That is: are you asking a technical question, looking for a line of code enabled by this signature, or a design question, asking why that line of code is worth enabling?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
class Person {}

class Student extends Person {}
```

`? super T` means `?` is a superclass (or interface) of `T`. 
That is, if a comparator is `Comparator<Person>`, since `Student` is inherited from `Person`, this comparator should still work on `Student`.

```
List<Student> students = ...
Collections.sort(students, new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        // compare person
        return 0;
    }
});
```

If we change `Comparator<? super T>` to `Comparator<T>`, the above code will not compile.